# EclipseLink record insert returns wrong id

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipselink, scope-identity

MSSQL(2008) and EclipseLink(2.4)

I'm inserting into a table with a trigger which does an insert into another table

When this happens EclipseLink returns the id of the record inserted into the other table by the trigger.

I assume I can get the correct id by getting EcliipseLink to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY.

The question is how to do this?

I need a solution for EclipseLink (JPA), I know how to get the id using sql.

Comment: After you `Insert` a `Select @IDImAfter = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` Will return the ID from the table you are inserting into rather than the table the trigger is inserting into.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer that I need a solution for EclipseLink. I am well aware that SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the id - the problem is to get EclipseLink to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`TableA` has a trigger that inserts into another table.  You issue a command like..

`INSERT INTO TableA (Field1, Field2) VALUES (@Value1, @Value2); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As MyRecID`

This will insert a record into `TableA` and return the `ID` of that record.

For more info read [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer that I need a solution for EclipseLink. I am well aware that SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the id - the problem is to get EclipseLink to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of adding a custom sequence object to EclipseLink to solve this issue here: http://helpdesk.ibs-aachen.de/2009/08/27/eclipselink-ms-sql-server-identity/

Comment: Unfortunately that example is very out of date. it also uses IDENT_CURRENT which will return the last id of any insert from any connection for the table. It can't simply be switched to SCOPE_IDENTITY as it appears that EclipseLink is pooling connections and calling SCOPE_IDENTITY on another connection returns null!

Comment: Is the ShouldAcquireValueAfterInsert flag being set to true on your sequence?  Another other alternative is you subclass the SQLServerPlatform and overrid buildSelectQueryForIdentity method to return your own query.  This is then added to the persistence unit using http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm

Comment: I subclassed SQLServerPlatform to use scope_identity(), and it still returned null. I then tried using scope_identity directly via JDBC and it still returned null! The only way I could get the id via JDBC was using getGeneratedKeys on the statement object that I used to execute the query.